# Best way to debug a python cron job in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use google appengine cron script to start up GCE instances

my pseudo-code is in python as below:

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute')
HTTP = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', http=HTTP)
# INSTANCE is the json description copied from the cloud console
request = compute.instances().insert(project=PROJECT_ID, body=INSTANCE, zone="us-central1-b" response = request.execute(http=HTTP)
```

I want to debug the cron job as the cron script is reported as failed in the cloud console unfortunately, logger.debug() never makes it to either the app engine logs, or to the web address of the app. I can run the cron script if I use the web address but, I want to debug it. Does anybody know how to?

Answer (score 0):

You could work with **standard logging**, and force set the logger to debug level for instance (not a perfect solution, instead you should probably use a logging config file http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html). Now I don't know if this also applies to google app engine.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.info("Starting my script")
.....
# something fails
LOG.error("Something happend")
.....
LOG.info("Finished my script")
```

This way you should get emails from your cron showing you the error message as it gets printed out to standard error.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is not with the logging aspect, its with the implementation of google appengine cron scripts, logging interface. I can manually trigger my cron scripts from the developer console using the rest interface, but the automated running fails! I will open another question.